# how do I get elasticsearch 5.6.3 cross cluster search working?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am stuck using elasticsearch/kibana 5.6.3. I need to enable cross cluster searching. I was able to get it working in 6.8.6 version but then found out I am stuck for now with older one (since we would have to upgrade dozens of servers sending data with an old version of fluentd). The documentation says to enable cluster settings from the console:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster-two": {
          "seeds": ["localhost:9301"]
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which generates this error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "persistent setting [cluster.remote.cluster-two.seeds.0], not dynamically updateable"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "persistent setting [cluster.remote.cluster-two.seeds.0], not dynamically updateable"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

My elastic search config file:

```
cluster.name: cluster
node.name: node-1
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

remote cluster:

```
cluster.name: remote-cluster
node.name: node-1
http.port: 9201
transport.tcp.port: 9301
```

I assume my error means I need to directly update this property in the config file. I tried a few options in elasticsearch.yml but no luck. Any idea what update I need to make to get cross cluster searching working?

Not working:

```
cluster.remote.cluster_two.seeds: ["127.0.0.1:9301"] 
cluster.remote.cluster_two.seeds: 127.0.0.1:9301 
cluster:
   remote:
       cluster_two: 
           seeds: 127.0.0.1:9301
```

Comment: What do you get when running `GET /_remote/info`?

Answer (score 0):

bleh ... I think I found it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-cross-cluster-search.html) but need to test it is working. They had different name for the yaml config:

- 5.6: search.remote.cluster_two.seeds
- 6.8: cluster.remote.cluster_two.seeds

At least the server starts up now. Also I can set that in the console without error:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster_two": {
          "seeds": ["localhost:9301"]
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```